# How do you use tokens instead of strings for targets?

Tags: f#, token, type-safety, f#-fake

I found that you can use [tokens](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/AdditionalSyntax.fs#L8-8) [instead of strings](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/AdditionalSyntax.fs#L11-11) for target names in [FAKE](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/) scripts. Could you translate my sample script into one that uses provided operators?

```
// include Fake lib
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll" open Fake

// Targets 
Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
    CleanDir "./build/")

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    trace "Hello World from FAKE" )

// Dependencies 
"Clean"   ==> "Default"

// start build 
RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following.

```
open Fake

// Targets 
Target?Clean (fun _ ->
    CleanDir "./build/")

Target?Default (fun _ ->
    trace "Hello World from FAKE" )

// Dependencies 
"Clean"   ==> "Default"

// start build 
RunTargetOrDefault?Default
```

For reference it might be worth having a look at other uses dynamic operator for F# [here](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2010/02/05/using-and-abusing-the-f-dynamic-lookup-operator/). So you get a better feel for what it is doing.